# Cannot reslolve method onSectionAttached(int)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm following along here: https://youtu.be/ZdBe_tPOY-A?t=4m53s and can't figure out why Android Studio is giving me an error on line 47: `OnSectionAttached(1);`. It's saying 'Cannot resolve method `OnSectionAttached(int)`, while it worked perfectly fine in the video (`he didn't have to define the method`).

Here's the file AboutFragment.java:

```
package trade.android.example.com.stitch;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by FiringBlanks on 7/12/2015.
 */

public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {

public static AboutFragment newInstance(){

    AboutFragment fragment = new AboutFragment();
    return fragment;
}

public AboutFragment(){

}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(1);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `onSectionAttached(int number)` method inside your `MainActivity` class. For ex:

```
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1: 
            // Your code
            break; 
        case 2: 
           // your code
            break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I just fast forwarded the video to 4:34 and see him defining this method. I should've finished the video before posting lol. Thanks!